# Use a newly-created column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm new to SQL. I do not have write access so I created a temp table `#temp` and did the following:

```
select 
    *, round(var1/100,0) as year 
from #temp

select 
    id_bucket, year, sum(b_flag) as num_b
from 
    #temp
group by 
    id_bucket, year 
order by 
    id_bucket, year
```

Then an error occurs that says

> invalid column name 'year'.

Why is that and what should I do?

Comment: `year` is a reserved word (used for the `datepart()` and `datename()` functions, for instance).  Name your columns something that is not reserved.  The list is here:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189822.aspx.  Also, you are *selecting* the column `year` from the table, but that doesn't change the table.  It only puts the column in the result set.

Comment: The column you create is not created in your table. You should use [subqueries](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189575%28v=sql.105%29.aspx).

Comment: Including the SQL code that creates your temporary table would probably be helpful.

Comment: From what you are trying to do, you don't even need write access to any tables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably the query you want is:

```
select id_bucket, round(var1 / 100,0), sum(b_flag) as num_b
from  #temp
group by id_bucket, round(var1 / 100, 0) 
order by  id_bucket, round(var1 / 100, 0);
```